# Use class parameter from generic class in Room Dao functions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I used [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0) to implement Room. However, I have to use this exact architecture with many different entities. I am trying to use generics to achieve it:

```
abstract class Architecture<T> {

    @androidx.room.Dao
    interface Dao {

        @Insert
        suspend fun insert(t : T)
    }
}
```

The T class parameter is supposed to be an entity. My problem is that I cannot access it from inside the interface.

Comment: You would only be able to reference it if you were defining an `inner class` instead of an interface. But this can't possibly work with Room for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: I didn't want to create a new interface for each entity. I know it's possible to use abstract interfaces, but it still a lot of work